# Is the shortest path using Dijkstra's Algorithm symmetric?

Tags: algorithms, symmetry

I am writing a code for finding the shortest path using Dijkstra's algorithm for an unweighted graph. I am wondering if this shortest path is symmetric i.e. if the shortest path from say A->E is A->D->F->E does it also mean that the shortest path from E->A should be E->F->D->A using Dijkstra's algorithm

```
  | A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F   |   G   |   H   |   I   |   J   |   

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

A | 0   |   17  |   15  |   29  |   41  |   27  |   31  |   24  |   6   |   46  |

B | 17  |   0   |   40  |   48  |   32  |   24  |   47  |   47  |   50  |   22  |

C | 15  |   40  |   0   |   49  |   1   |   2   |   24  |   23  |   19  |   38  |

D | 29  |   48  |   49  |   0   |   27  |   46  |   29  |   33  |   14  |   32  |

E | 41  |   32  |   1   |   27  |   0   |   40  |   11  |   2   |   22  |   33  |

F | 27  |   24  |   2   |   46  |   40  |   0   |   27  |   25  |   18  |   25  |

G | 31  |   47  |   24  |   29  |   11  |   27  |   0   |   34  |   50  |   10  |

H | 24  |   47  |   23  |   33  |   2   |   25  |   34  |   0   |   21  |   24  |

I | 6   |   50  |   19  |   14  |   22  |   18  |   50  |   21  |   0   |   15  |

J | 46  |   22  |   38  |   32  |   33  |   25  |   10  |   24  |   15  |   0   |

Find the shortest path between (seperate vertice with comma e.g A, B represents A to B): A,E
The shortest path is A->I->E and the weight is 28.0


Find the shortest path between (seperate vertice with comma e.g A, B represents A to B): E,A
The shortest path is E->C->A and the weight is 16.0
```

Comment: If the graph is undirected - yes. Otherwise, there may not be such path at all.

Comment: Aren't there places in the algorithm where there's a tie, and you have to make some choice? The rule for making the choice will probably introduce an asymmetry. Why not try some examples, and see for yourself?

Comment: @Marcin, what if there's more than one shortest path?

Comment: Well, I consider all such paths "shortest", and so the reversed path is definitely also "shortest", though of course not "the shortest". If the question if strictly "what will Dijkstra produce" then no, I suppose it won't necesserily be the reversed path in case of ties.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Please what do you mean by more than 1 shortest paths (SPs)? You mean two SPs that are equal?

Comment: Yes, two paths of equal, minimal length. You might get one going forward, the other going back.

Comment: I followed a pseudocode I got online and sometimes I get results that are not the same path with one being longer than the other. So that means I am doing something wrong right?

Comment: The graph is undirected, right?

Comment: If the graph is undirected, and the edge weights/lengths are positive, then the shortest distance creates a metric, i.e. it is non-negative, symmetric and satisfies triangle inequality.

Comment: @YankiTwizzy Yes, if your graph is *undirected*, the shortest distance between two vertices is the same when going form one to the other or vice versa. If you get different results, something is not right -- either the graph is not undirected (e.g. ), or your implementation is incorrect. What about providing an example of the graph you were testing the algorithm on, along with the paths you found?

Comment: @PeterKošinár I have added a sample graph I generated and some sample output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Warning: The numbers below were calculated by hand, so there might be mistakes or typos; take them with grain of salt!*

The path `A->I->E` your implementation found is not the shortest one. I'll refer to the [pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode) from Wikipedia:

- In the first iteration of the `while` loop, we look at vertex `A` which has distance $0$ and adjust the array `dist` array which becomes identical to the first row of your matrix.

  ```
  | A | B  | C  | D  | E  | F  | G  | H  | I  | J  |   
  | 0 | 17 | 15 | 29 | 41 | 27 | 31 | 24 | 6  | 46 |
  ```
- The second iteration picks vertex `I` with distance $6$, since that is the smallest one among the unprocessed ones. The `dist` array will be updated,using `I` as a shortcut whenever possible (e.g. for `C` or `D`, but not for `B`):

  ```
  | A | B  | C  | D  | E  | F  | G  | H  | I  | J  |   
  | 0 | 17 | 15 | 20 | 28 | 24 | 31 | 24 | 6  | 21 |
  ```
- Third iteration picks vertex `C` with distance $15$, updating the distances as follows:

  ```
  | A | B  | C  | D  | E  | F  | G  | H  | I  | J  |   
  | 0 | 17 | 15 | 20 | 16 | 17 | 31 | 24 | 6  | 21 |
  ```
- Finally, the fourth iteration picks vertex `E` with distance $16$ and celebrates that it has found the shortest distance between `A` and `E`.

Your result looks more like an application of a *greedy* algorithm, which always takes the shortest available connection between the current point and any of its neighbours -- and this graph serves as a good example of why this approach doesn't work :-)

Comment: I have fixed it. Thanks. I was missing something in my code